# Loading resources using dictionary (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making it possible to change skins for a 2D character and Im running into a problem

Sprites loading looks like this

```
    private void LoadResources()
{
    _faces = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_face");
    _hoods = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_hood");

    _elbowsLeft = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_elbow_l");
    _elbowsRight = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_elbow_r");
    _shouldersLeft = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_shoulder_l");
    _shouldersRight = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_shoulder_r");
    _wristsLeft = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_wrist_l");
    _wristsRight = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_wrist_r");

    _torsos = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_torso");
    _pelvises = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_pelvis");

    _legsLeft = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_leg_l");
    _legsRight = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_leg_r");
    _bootsLeft = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_boot_l");
    _bootsRight = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(@"Rogue/Rogue_boot_r");
}
```

It looks quite cumbersome and difficult to understand

I would like to get something like this, how can I implement it?

```
_spritesPaths = new Dictionary<Sprite[], string>()
    {
        {_faces, "Rogue_face"},
        {_hoods, "Rogue_hood"},

        {_elbowsLeft, "Rogue_elbow_l"},
        {_elbowsRight, "Rogue_elbow_r"},
        {_shouldersLeft, "Rogue_shoulder_l"},
        {_shouldersRight, "Rogue_shoulder_r"},
        {_wristsLeft, "Rogue_wrist_l"},
        {_wristsRight, "Rogue_wrist_r"},

        {_torsos, "Rogue_torso"},
        {_pelvises, "Rogue_pelvis"},

        {_legsLeft, "Rogue_leg_l"},
        {_legsRight, "Rogue_leg_r"},
        {_bootsLeft, "Rogue_boot_l"},
        {_bootsRight, "Rogue_boot_r"}
    };

private void LoadResources()
{
    foreach (var pair in _spritesPaths)
        pair.Key = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>($@"Rogue/{pair.Value}"); //this does not work
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried. There after all looks to be a repeated pattern

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried string addition?

```
pair.Key = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Rogue/" + pair.Value);
```